# Can I disable all compilation in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

This is a new one for me. I have been asked, for legal reasons, to setup a laptop with Visual Studio, but to disable the ability to compile projects/solutions. The purpose is to enable browsing of the source code, but not allow building or executing it.

Yes, I know this is really a stupid question and unfortunately I can't get into too many details. I've asked about using alternative text editors, but I have been told no. So until I can prove it isn't possible (or that I have at least made a reasonable effort), I have to try and make this work. Notepad++ would be an excellent alternative, but that has been rejected.

This would be in Visual Studio 2010 or later. Is there any way that I can do this?

**UPDATE**

After trying [Marius Bancila's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197678/366904) of removing the compilers and MSBuild, I was surprised to find out that VS continued to work fine (except for building, of course). I did not expect that functionality like <kbd>F12</kbd> (Go To Definition) would continue to work.

This may mean that there still remains the ability to build something somewhere somehow. But as it stands with MSBuild permanently deleted and the Visual Studio Build command not working, it'll take some effort to get around it (if a way in fact does exist).

Comment: Use notepad instead. Visual Studio is an Integrated Development Environment absolutely not designed to meet the insanity of your requirements.

Comment: If you're going for only code visibility, Notepad++ is never a bad choice.

Comment: If you give them the source code then what's stopping them from copying the source code to another machine and compiling it there?

Comment: The whole laptop is locked down - no usb, no network and it can only be used under supervision. And Notepad++ is already installed but I have been told that doesn't meet the requirements (I'm guessing they mean the court's requirements).

Comment: May I ask what legal reasons?

Comment: @shf301 - all network and peripheral ports are disabled, the optical drive has been removed, and the hard drive is encrypted. As it is it took me 2 days to get an admin to enable the usb port so I could copy the VS installer onto the machine.

Comment: @MariusBancila - a lawsuit. I don't want to get anyone (myself included) into trouble by saying any more than that.

Comment: @MariusBancila this sort of thing tends to happen when a company is asked to turn over source code in a suit involving such things as copyright and/or patent infringement. The prosecuting party (or a third party, sometimes provided by the court) must be provided means to review the source code, without the ability to modify it, build and run it, or copy it to another storage device or computer.

Comment: So what is going to keep the user from just copying the source code elsewhere and compiling/running it on a properly setup environment?

Comment: @Mysticial the access is meant to be supervised, and there is no access to the outside world.

Comment: @andy256 So why can't the supervisor keep the user from compiling the code?

Comment: @Mysticial From what the OP has said, this is part of a court case. We can use all the logic we like, but the OP has to comply with the (presumed) court order.

Comment: Maybe instead of installing a full version of Visual Studio, perhaps you could install the Visual Studio Shell. I don't know the full details on how it works but as I understand it, it's meant to give a bare UI for developers to be able to create their own editor for any language. I believe that includes leaving out any specific build tools or other language-specific features. I think syntax highlighting remains so you probably don't need to do anything more than that.

Comment: @Mysticial as mentioned in previous comments all input/output ports were disabled and locked down by a sys admin. You can't use USB/Optical/Network/Serial - nothing. This prevents the scenario you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what projects should not be possible to build (VC++, VC#, VB.NET, F#, etc.). Starting with VS2010 they are all built using MSBuild. So if you delete MSBuild they will not be able to build from inside Visual Studio. However, one can still be able to build from the command line, so the only possibility I see is that you delete all the compilers that come with Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried deleting all the mentioned utilities, but it wasn't until I removed MSBuild.exe that it actually broke. As a extra caution I removed link.exe and all instances of csc.exe since all the code is written in C#.

Comment: @Mark, where did you delete MSBuild from? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\? That is part of the .NET runtime, and is used by applications other than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bit crazy, but if you really have to ...

Try deleting some important binaries after installing Visual Studio e.g. linker (link.exe) and compiler (cl.exe).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: @pnuts see the UPDATE section in the OP - that was the last status of that "project".

Answer (score 2):

Use a text editor instead.  Notepad++ even comes with color syntax highlighting.

You cannot prevent people from compiling the code.  Visual Studio Express is available to anyone, and the compiler can be executed from the command line, without Visual Studio's help.

Comment: Thanks, I actually suggested this. But unfortunately I was told they already tried that and it must be Visual Studio